# how do you keep loop count when looping through the output of a property in python?

Tags: python, loops, properties, counter

so I'm looping through a property in python. 
By the way this is just example code... not what I'm working with: 
I did not wan't to post what I'm working on, because it's hundreds of lines. 
but I think this conveys my point.

```
@property
def tokenize(self):
    (lots of compex operations)

   return tokens
```

and in another method i'm looping through the output of that property

```
def anther_method(self):
   count = 0
   for a in self.tokenize:
       count += 1
```

but the problem is that if that property outputs a list lets say... and it then outputs another list, the counter will go back down to zero, thus I have no idea how to keep track of my loop count. is there any way of keeping my count, without doing some sort of list comprehension to the output, because I wan't to keep the data types that this property is returning the same.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

here is an example of the output before I loop through it:

```
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494E10>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023EE470>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D50>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023EEE90>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D90>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023F53D0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023F53F0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023F5410>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494F10>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023F5470>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494E50>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023FB230>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494E30>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023FB510>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494DB0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x023FB770>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494DB0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x02401530>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494F10>, <__main__.Character object at 0x02409850>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494F10>, <__main__.Character object at 0x02413870>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494FD0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241E3F0>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494E90>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241E4F0>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494DB0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241E790>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241E7B0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241E7D0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241E7F0>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241E810>]
[<__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D30>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241EB10>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241EB30>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241EB50>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241EB70>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494E90>, <__main__.Character object at 0x0241EC10>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494E50>, <__main__.Character object at 0x02494330>, <__main__.Character object at 0x02494350>, <__main__.Character object at 0x02494370>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494D90>, <__main__.Character object at 0x02494450>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494F10>, <__main__.Character object at 0x02494590>, <__main__.Sentence object at 0x02494FD0>]
```

you can probably see why it's splitting the counter up. because every time that list changes it's resetting the counter.

Comment: I can't understand your question.  What do you mean "it outputs another list"?  When will the counter go back down to zero?  Are you saying you are calling `another_method` multiple times and you want to keep the count across multiple calls?

Comment: so the system I'm building splits words, sentences, and paragraphs into their own data types, so once it hits another paragraph it outputs it as a different list, or that is my assumption at this point, and thus it returns the count back to zero.

Comment: Iterators don't work that way. Once they terminate an iteration, they're done. The for loop terminates, count is a count of whatever the iterator produced and your another_method() exits. You should work on your some_method() iterator first, figure out what you want it to yield, and then work on the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to structure your code for another level.  If you're trying to parse paragraphs, and paragraphs contain sentences, and sentences contain words, then you need one more enclosing method for paragraphs.  Then each paragraph will start counting sentences at zero.  Without knowing more about `some_method()`, it's hard to be more specific.